# Mixing personal (SMTP/POP) and business (Exchange) mail in Outlook

Tags: exchange, smtp, outlook, pop3

Although I haven't done it, I'm pretty sure that you can set up Outlook (2010) to work with both SMTP/POP email and with Exchange simultaneously.

Here is the scenario: I work with a group of independent contractors and we want to have joint email, calendar and contacts for the work we do together - so we're thinking of using a hosted Exchange solution for this purpose.  At the same time, we want to maintain our own individual  personal/professional email/calendar/contacts using our respective SMTP/POP accounts.

If we are using Outlook, is it possible for these two to coincide peacefully?  Are there any pitfalls or compromises involved here?  Will Outlook happily show combined personal and exchange mail/contacts/calendars while keeping the personal stuff hidden from other Exchange users?  Or will it be a matter of having distinct mail accounts and calendars that have to be selected one at a time on the left hand side, without any integrated view of inbox/calendar/contacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this myself.

I have my work-exchange, my personal Google Apps and iCloud all syncing to the same Outlook on my Outlook - Work laptop, it works without any problems.

This is how my calendar looks:
[image]

I think you can consolidate them into one view, rather then x separate panels.

Comment: Thanks Bart.  In your setup, do you have one calendar with events from multiple accounts or do you have to select and view multiple calendars one after the other?

Comment: @JoelBrown Updated above ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, multiple accounts can coexist well in Outlook. Even accounts of differing types, like Exchange, IMAP and POP3. By default, recent versions of Outlook will show each account under its own folder structure in the left pane of the main Window. A quick look on my Mac's Outlook 2011 shows that there's an option to allow a unified mailbox that groups items from all of the accounts into one view. Outlook 2010 doesn't have this, and it appears to [require a bit of a hack](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/set-up-single-inbox-folder-for-all-accounts-in-outlook-2010/) to work this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link.  I could live with having two different inboxes if I had to.  The real problem would be two calendars.

Comment: The calendars will display in one window in layers. You can show the combined information or each account at a time. The calendar view is well-integrated.